# BTC not received after sending

Tags: transactions, utxo, output

I have a transaction sent from Coinbase on 12 Dec 2017.  i can see it on the blockchain, fees taken but the rest is unspent.

How can I force the transaction to complete.
Why didn't it complete

Answera in laymans terms please as I'm new to this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unspend just means that the part you received (this part is called a transaction-output) is not spend yet. Your transaction is complete.

It would show *spend* if you e.g. payed someone with your transaction-output. Then they would have an unspend transaction output.